# an object reference is required for the nonstatic field method

Tags: c#, asp.net, checkbox, checkboxlist

I have addEvent method in my .aspx.cs file. In which i want to use my checkbox and cheboxList but when i use it is shows me the error as shown in image below. as well as i have specify the code of my page hope you get the idea the problem which i am facing.

I have page something link as shown in the image and at the ADD EVENT it shows me error. When i remove the STATIC Keyword my calender ADD Button not working.

[image]

```
protected void chkRecSch_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
if (chkRecSch.Checked == true) {
//BindCheckBoxList();
BindCheckBoxListWithNextSevenDays();
weekChk.Visible = true;
}
else { weekChk.Visible = false; }

}

public void BindCheckBoxListWithNextSevenDays()
{
DateTime today = DateTime.Now;

DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dt.Columns.Add("Id", typeof(int));
dt.Columns.Add("date", typeof(string));

for (int i = 1; i <= 7; i++)
{
dt.Rows.Add(i, today.AddDays(i).ToString("dddd yyyy-MM-dd")); // (dddd yyyy-MM-dd) will return the date in following format (Wednesday 2020/02-05)
}
chkweek.DataSource = dt;
chkweek.DataBind();
}

[System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
public static int addEvent(ImproperCalendarEvent improperEvent)
{
if (chkRecSch.Checked == true)
{
 foreach (ListItem li in weekChk.Items)
 {
 if (li.Selected == true)
 {
 Label1.Text += li + " ";
 }
 }
}

CalendarEvent cevent = new CalendarEvent()
{

title = "Schedular Master",
description = "Schedular Master",

StartDate = improperEvent.start,
StartTime = improperEvent.startTime,

EndDate = improperEvent.end,

EndTime = improperEvent.endTime,


UserID = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["AdminID"].ToString(),
ProviderId = improperEvent.ProviderId

};

if (CheckAlphaNumeric(cevent.title) && CheckAlphaNumeric(cevent.description))
{
int key = EventDAO.AddScheduleMaster(cevent);

return key;

}
```

Comment: You can not use nonstatic object inside of static method. This means you should remove static keyword from addEvent for weekChk to be accessible

Comment: Please, do not share code as images

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski ok sir i have edit my post and write the code hope now it is fine. i am fresher so.

Comment: @donatasj87 i tried to remove the static keywork as per your suggestion sir but my ADD button not works so help me. i have edit my post and specify my page code.

Comment: @JohnathanBarclay i have gone though this post sir but my Leader told me find the other solution. Static Keywork must their so that's why i have Add New Question.If your have any solution please suggest.

Comment: You probably need to investigate [`UpdatePanel`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.updatepanel)s